# Cannot mount second 1TB harddrive in Linux, works fine in Windows 8.1

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, windows

So I have this problem with my second hard-drive that I have been trying to fix for quite awhile now with no luck. I have searched around to try to find solutions to my problem but nothing seemed to be quite like mine.

Basically, I have a Windows 8.1/Antergos (basically Arch Linux) dual boot on my 128GB SSD, and then I have a 1TB hard-drive for storing all my other data. I formatted the 1TB hard-drive through Windows because I didn't have Linux installed at the time.

I cannot mount my second hard-drive because it has an "unknown" filesystem, even though I know it is NTFS.

Here's what gparted shows:
[image: gparted output]

And some other (hopefully) useful information...

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   128M  0 part 
└─sda2   8:2    0 931.4G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   350M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0  96.5G  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0   6.7G  0 part /
└─sdb6   8:22   0   8.3G  0 part /home

$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
[sudo] password for matthieu: 

Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C96FA339-748A-11E3-BE68-BC5FF4E9FCAE
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Device           Start          End   Size Type
/dev/sda1           34       262177   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2       264192   1953523711 931.4G unknown
```

Here's what happens when I try to mount the drive...

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Comment: What does `sudo file -s /dev/sda2` say?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu `/dev/sda2: data`

Comment: Did you try `mount -t ntfs`? and is `ntfs` even supported by your kernel?

Comment: It's not just NTFS. It's NTFS inside of some Microsoft LVM-like thing. Probably this one: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/storage-spaces-pools ... I'm not sure if Windows can convert it back to a normal partition table; if it can, that'd be your best bet.

Comment: @derobert Yep, I'm pretty sure I set it up as described in that link. Is there any way to get around it, or will I have to reformat the drive completely?

Comment: @Matthieu Quick searching failed to find a way to read that from Linux. I'm not sure if a reformat is required, Windows might be able to convert it back... Probably [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be the best bet for asking if its possible (in Windows) to convert it back to a normal partition. You can leave this one open, as maybe someone else knows a way to read Windows Storage Spaces from Linux (and that's a different question, so it's not cross-posting).

Comment: @derobert Cool, thanks! I will look into it and post my findings (if any) in the original post.

Comment: @Matthieu, maybe the articles ["Converting Dynamic Disks Back to Basic Disks"](http://thelazyadmin.com/2007/01/converting-dynamic-disks-back-to-basic-disks/) or ["How to non-destructively convert dynamic disks to basic disks"](http://mypkb.wordpress.com/2007/03/28/how-to-non-destructively-convert-dynamic-disks-to-basic-disks/) can help you.

Comment: @derobert, So do you mean that Windows "NTFS" is not true "NTFS"?

Comment: @Pacerier where did I say that?

Comment: @derobert, I'm referring to your [first comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147970/cannot-mount-second-1tb-harddrive-in-linux-works-fine-in-windows-8-1?noredirect=1#comment239911_147970) which I don't quite understand.

Comment: @Pacerier Windows 8 apparently has something like Linux's LVM called "storage spaces". In Linux terms, that NTFS filesystem sits on a LV inside, and `/dev/sda2` is one of the PVs  that make up the VG. At least when I looked back in August '14, I couldn't find tools that understand Storage Spaces, allowing Linux to use the LVs inside.